# Выполнение запроса с параметрами в ms access с unicode

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, access, ms-access

Здравствуйте. Есть БД MS SQL в которой текстовые поля типа `nvarchar` в unicode. В этих полях хранятся значения на кириллице. При выполнении запроса к базе я пишу `WHERE [dbo].[mytablename].[mycplumnname] = N'Значение на кириллице'` и всё работает отлично, т.к. `N` писать необходимо. Но, проблема возникает, когда такой же запрос выполнять через Access, причём с вводом параметров `WHERE [dbo].[myTableName].[myColumnName] = [Введите сюда значение:]`. Такой запрос уже ничего не возвращает. Посоветуйте, как исправить?

Comment: Пытался так `StrConv([Введите сюда значение:]; 64)` тоже всё тщетно.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
[dbo].[mytablename].[mycplumnname] = cast([Введите сюда значение:] as nvarchar)
```

Comment: Access не понимает эту функцию, увы.

Comment: Вы без N вводите значение?

Comment: Какая коллация используется для столбца mycplumnname?

Comment: ввожу без N, т.к. синтаксис `N[Введите сюда значение:]` не съедается Access. Коолация Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

Comment: N[Введите сюда значение:] - это я не понял (N). Если у вас киррилическая коллация, то N можно не писать вовсе. Проверьте без него.